# Prove that this doesn't converge almost surely to 0

Tags: random-variable, convergence

Suppose we have $X_n$ a random variable, that can take two values:

$X_n =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{with probability 1 - $\frac{1}{2n}$,} \\
n, & \text{with probability $\frac{1}{2n}$} \end{cases}$

Does $X_n$ converge almost sure to $0$? I don't need a rigorous proof, but I would like to have an intuition for why it doesn't converge almost surely to 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the contrapositive Borel Cantelli Lemma, which says that if your events $A_i$ are independent and $\sum_i P(A_i)=\infty$ then $A_i$ occur infinitely often. In this case, pick $A_i=\{X_i>1\}$. Can you finish it from here?

For "intuition," $X_n$ grows too fast with high probability. If you want, modify $P(X_n=n)=\frac{1}{2n}$ to $P(X_n)=\frac{1}{2n^2}$  [and modify $P(X_n=0)=1-P(X_n)$].. Now apply the usual Borel Cantelli to conclude in this case that $X_n$ converges to $0$ almost surely.

Comment: Sorry, i'm not familiar with Borel Cantelli, i'm kind of new in Probability Theory.

Comment: The thing is that i want to show that this does not converges to 0 almost surely.

Comment: @S.Cow: How did you happen upon this question then? Borel Cantelli is pretty much the *only* tool we have for showing something converges almost surely.

Comment: @S.Cow: Yes, that's why you need the contrapositive Borel Cantelli Lemma: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma#Converse_result

Comment: @AlexR . It might help if you separate out your growth suggestion from your response. I think S.Cow is getting confusing your suggestion with your response in your answer.

Comment: @dsaxton: I made an assumption based on a prior distribution over such questions.

Comment: @S.Cow almost sure convergence is a rather technical topic, so why do you need to know if you don't understand Borel-Cantelli or a modicum of measure theory?

Answer (score 2):

You can't prove it because $X_n$ could either converge to zero almost surely or not.  You haven't provided enough information.

As has already been pointed out if the $X_n$ are independent then the fact that $X_n = n$ infinitely often with probability one follows from the second Borel-Cantelli lemma.  However, we could let $U \sim$ uniform$(0, 1)$ and set $X_n = n$ if $U < 1 / 2n$.  Then our sequence satisfies the conditions of the problem and $X_n \to 0$ almost surely.

Comment: I asked a question related to this answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/466852/is-the-independence-of-this-sequence-of-random-variables-not-implicitly-given-wh).

Answer (score 0):

Can i just pick for example a $n=4$ and then i write:

for $i \ge 4$ we have:

$X_i =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{with probability $\frac{7}{8}$,} \\
4, & \text{with probability $\frac{1}{8}$} \end{cases}$

and then obviusly $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} Prob( \lvert x_i\rvert > \varepsilon, \forall i \ge 4) \neq 0 $ ??

Comment: I don't think this proves it though. How is it obvious that in the limit the probability doesn't approach 0 when $1/(2n)$ does approach 0 as $n$ approaches infinity?