# Almost Sure Convergence, intuition

Tags: probability, convergence, intuition

i'm having a little trouble to prove that this random variable does not converge almost surely:

$X_{n} =
\begin{cases}
0   & \text{with probability}: 1 - \frac{1}{n} \\
1 - \frac{1}{n}, & \text{with probability}: \frac{1}{2n} \\
1 & \text{with probability}: \frac{1}{2n}
\end{cases}$

I have already shown that $X_{n}$ converges in probability to $0$, i think I can also prove that converges in quadratic mean to $0$, but my intuition tell's me that it does not converges almost surely to $0$.

Can someone give a mathematical proof? Is my intuition right? I'm thinking, that for almost sure convergence, I need that for some value of $N > n_{0}$, the probability of $X_{n}$ not being $0$ should be 0, but that is not the case here.

Comment: From the way the question is phrased, I'm guessing this is self study.  So, instead of an answer, hints:  1) How often, in an infinite sequence of $X_n$, will $X_n-0 > \epsilon$ for some arbitrary $\epsilon \in (0,1)$?  2) Borel-Cantelli.

Comment: Are the $X_n$ independent? Strictly speaking, as it stands there isn't enough information provided in the question to give an answer - there may or may not be a.s. convergence. See the answer by dsaxton at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/213526

Comment: @jbowman i'm not familiar with Borel-Cantelli. I just need the intuition actually, not the proof. I'm thinking that does not converges almost surely to $0$ because the probability of $X_{n} \neq 0$ is always positive. Small, but possitive. I'm right?

Comment: You're almost right.  The idea is that if $\Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty} p(X_n \neq 0)$ is finite, then the probability that event $X_n \neq 0$ happens infinitely often is 0, which implies that eventually, almost surely, it won't happen any more, which in turn implies almost sure convergence (writing loosely.)  Borel-Cantelli gives you the first step.  Now in your case, $\Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty}1/2n = \infty$, so, by the second Borel-Cantelli lemma, $X_n = 0$ occurs infinitely often, and you don't get almost sure convergence.  And @S.Catterall is correct, you need independence also.